# Where can I see the actual cost for Azure Cosmos backups?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-billing

Where can I see my actual cost for Azure Cosmos backups? They are nowhere to be found in the portal or on the invoice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create or use Azure Cosmos DB resources, you might get charged for the following meters:

Database operations - You're charged for it based on the request units(RU/s) provisioned or consumed:

Standard (manual) provisioned throughput - You are billed an hourly rate for the RU/s provisioned on your container or database.
Auto scale provisioned throughput - You are billed based on the maximum number of RU/s the system scaled up to in each hour.
Consumed storage - You're charged for it based the total amount of storage (in GBs) consumed by your data and indexes for a given hour.

There is an additional charge in case you are using the Azure Cosmos DB features like **backup storage**, analytical storage, Availability zones, Multi-region writes. At the end of your billing cycle, the charges for each meter are summed. **Your bill or invoice shows a section for all Azure Cosmos DB costs**. There's a separate line item for each meter. To learn more, see the [Pricing article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cosmos-db/).

If you want to view the cost in the Azure portal , you can go to Azure cost analysis report in the [Azure cost management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/costs/quick-acm-cost-analysis) blade from your subscription the resource was created by filtering cost by resource.

**Please also note:** Azure Cosmos DB accounts that have continuous backup enabled will incur an additional monthly charge to store the backup and to restore your data. The restore cost is added every time the restore operation is initiated. If you configure an account with continuous backup but don't restore the data, only backup storage cost is included in your bill.

Additional Info: https://cosmos.azure.com/capacitycalculator/